# Beginner's Mistake

Tags: c++

I know this is probably a dumb question but I am a beginner and I just started learning today. I am using Dev C++ and I wrote my first code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" ;
    return 0;
}
```

I click to compile and run. Nothing comes up. Then I click just "run" and it said it is not compiled yet.

I think there might be errors and I would have gladly fixed them myself but I don't know where I can see the errors in Dev C++.

Could this be a compiler error or did I mess up something in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: It works: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d1188cb82a937c6706b0e700080bfade

Comment: You haven't compiled it properly.

Comment: People still use Dev C++? Wow...

Comment: This looks like a problem with the configuration. Dev C++ (AFAIK) uses an external compiler, and that might not be installed... You should search the Dev C++ forums. Other than that, you can use a plain editor and compile from the command line, which although it may seem harder might actually be easier in the sense that there are less moving parts and abstractions. Either it works, or it does not.

Comment: You would want to briefly describe your problem in the title instead of "Beginner's Mistake"

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but please don't learn the habit of `using namespace std;`. It will cause problems later. Drop that line, and refer to `cout` as `std::cout`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your program exits before it manages to write everything out to the console. Try adding new line to the output, like this:

```
cout << "Hello World" << endl;
```

When you write to `cout`, the data is not transfered to the screen right away, out of efficiency considerations. Writing to the screen is relatively slow, so the program prefers to do it in "bursts". The text is accumulated in a *buffer* until a special command is given to *flush* the buffer, or the buffer fills up. Writing out `endl` forces a flush, so the output will appear on the screen before your program exits.